# Creating a nested dictionary by adding elements from a list

Tags: python

I have the following list and dict:

```
external_list = ["122479-6-995220", "122479-2-112234", "223344-1-434312", "223344-3-575342", "223344-0-092312", "223344-4-215452", "338855-5-828822", "338855-7-234567", "338855-8-000000", "440099-9-111111"]
internal_list = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "F"]

dict = {
    "122479-6-995220": "11",
    "122479-2-112234": "11",
    "223344-1-434312": "12",
    "223344-3-575342": "13",
    "223344-0-092312": "14",
    "223344-4-215452": "16",
    "338855-5-828822": "16",
    "338855-7-234567": "16",
    "338855-8-000000": "F",
    "440099-9-111111": "F"
}
```

I want to get this nested dict:

```
updated_dict = {
    "122479-6-995220": { "11": 1, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "122479-2-112234": { "11": 1, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "223344-1-434312": { "11": 0, "12": 1, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "223344-3-575342": { "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 1, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "223344-0-092312": { "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 1, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "223344-4-215452": { "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 1, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "338855-5-828822": { "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 1, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "338855-7-234567": { "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 1, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 0},
    "338855-8-000000": { "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 1},
    "440099-9-111111": { "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "F": 1},
}
```

Basically i add to each internal list of keys all the elements from the list with values set to zero if they weren't already there, else 1.

A solution that creates a brand new dictionary would also be good.

Edit:
Before i edited the post i used another dictionary structure, same lists:

```
dict = {
    "122479-6-995220": { "11": 1},
    "122479-2-112234": { "11": 1},
    "223344-1-434312": { "12": 1},
    "223344-3-575342": { "13": 1},
    "223344-0-092312": { "14": 1},
    "223344-4-215452": { "16": 1},
    "338855-5-828822": { "16": 1},
    "338855-7-234567": { "16": 1},
    "338855-8-000000": { "F": 1},
    "440099-9-111111": { "F": 1},
}
```

The solution posted by metatoaster refers to this

Comment: Instead of using the default value `"0"`, use that as the default value for the original `dict.get` using the key; you might want something like `dict[s].get(p, 0)` instead of `"0"`.  Also, rename `dict` to something like `mapping` as `dict` has a default assignment for that type.

Comment: ... Would have been useful to include the original attempt that you had made rather than deleting it, you were on the right track, since this solution `{s: {p: mapping[s].get(p, 0) for (p,v) in mapping.items() if v != 1 for p in internal_list} for s in external_list}` is based on that.

Comment: @metatoaster you are right, i'm editing the post again to show the attempt for other users, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
external_list = ["122479-6-995220", "122479-2-112234", "223344-1-434312", "223344-3-575342", "223344-0-092312", "223344-4-215452", "338855-5-828822", "338855-7-234567", "338855-8-000000", "440099-9-111111"]
internal_list = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "F"]

dict = {
    "122479-6-995220": "11",
    "122479-2-112234": "11",
    "223344-1-434312": "12",
    "223344-3-575342": "13",
    "223344-0-092312": "14",
    "223344-4-215452": "16",
    "338855-5-828822": "16",
    "338855-7-234567": "16",
    "338855-8-000000": "F",
    "440099-9-111111": "F"
}

updated_dict = {i :{j:int(j == dict[i]) for j in internal_list} for i in external_list}
```

You can use the above dict comprehension to get what you want.

Output :

```
122479-6-995220 {'11': 1, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
122479-2-112234 {'11': 1, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
223344-1-434312 {'11': 0, '12': 1, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
223344-3-575342 {'11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 1, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
223344-0-092312 {'11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 1, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
223344-4-215452 {'11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 1, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
338855-5-828822 {'11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 1, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
338855-7-234567 {'11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 1, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 0}
338855-8-000000 {'11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 1}
440099-9-111111 {'11': 0, '12': 0, '13': 0, '14': 0, '15': 0, '16': 0, '17': 0, '18': 0, '19': 0, 'F': 1}
```

Comment: good to know, you can mark it as accepted if that is the case @Piazza